# nginx and try_files confusion

Tags: linux, php, nginx, redirect

I am confused with how **try_files** works on nginx, this needs to be done on a live production server so can't test before being 100% sure. I am using `header("X-Accel-Redirect: /out/" . $fname);` to deliver files from PHP which is handled by the following in nginx config :

```
location /out {
            root /home;
            internal;
        }
```

Now I have added an additional disk to my server to store files, I want nginx to first find the file at `/home` and if not found on `/home2`. How should I achieve this setup, is code below valid and should get done what I need :

```
location /out {
            try_files /home /home2;
            internal;
        }
```

Also, do we need the root directive anymore when using try_files ?

Comment: What situation of you have yourself in that you can't test this somewhere? It's trivial, just fire up a virtual box vm and mock it up!

Comment: creating a VM and setting-up a exact system is very time consuming, I guess it is more efficient to tap into knowledge of someone having experience in same here.

Comment: no, its not (very time consuming), esp. when considering to have a test environment especially for your case now (that is: someone who needs to test out things first). but, he, it's your uptime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nginx documentation on try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files):

> Syntax: try_files file ... uri
>
> Checks for the existence of files in order, and returns the first file that is found. A trailing slash indicates a directory - $uri /. In the event that no file is found, an internal redirect to the last parameter is invoked. Do note that only the last parameter causes an internal redirect, former ones just sets the internal URI pointer. The last parameter is the fallback URI and *must* exist, or else an internal error will be raised. Named locations can be used. Unlike with rewrite, $args are not automatically preserved if the fallback is not a named location. If you need args preserved, you must do so explicitly.

As the documentation specifies, you need to have a fallback URI that must exist. You could try something like this in your setup:

```
location /out {
  try_files /home/ /home2/ /index.html;
  internal;
}
```

You do not need the `root`-directive in the `location`-block if you have specified the correct paths using `try_files`.

Comment: Thanks, can I omit the fallback uri or send the correct 404 header  instead if nothing is found which also should be the valid case (404 if file is not there).

Comment: No, the fallback uri *must exist* as the documentation tells. About sending the 404 header, I do not know.

Comment: `location /out {
  try_files /home/ /home2/ /error/404.html;
  internal;
}` Failed for me and always delivered 404.html even when file existed in /home/out folder. I even tried /home (removed the trailing slash) but it still failed !!